# Bing Maps tryPixelToLocation on Polygon

Tags: javascript, bing-maps

I'm trying to create a concave polygon by getting user clicks on a map. I can create convex polygons just fine. But when I attempt to create the concave polygon I have to click on the polygon itself giving me the following error:

> e.target.tryPixelToLocation is not a function

Allow me to elaborate further. The user clicks on the map and a pin is placed on the map to show where they just clicked. They click two more time and they now have a triangle drawn on the map. When they attempt to click inside that triangle to draw the fourth point, creating a concave polygon, they get the above error.

The code I am using is below

```
function GetMap(sender, args) {
    map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapDiv"), {
        credentials: "XXXXX",
        enableSearchLogo: false,
        enableClickableLogo: false,
        disableBirdseye: true
    });
    map.setView({
        zoom: 17,
        center: new Microsoft.Maps.Location($('#startLatitude').val(), $('#startLongitude').val()),
        mapTypeId: Microsoft.Maps.MapTypeId.aerial,
        labelOverlay: Microsoft.Maps.LabelOverlay.visible
    });
    Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(map, 'click', getUserClick);
}

function getUserClick(e) {
    alert(e.targetType); // <--- When this is 'Polygon' we get the error 
    if (e.mouseMoved === false && e.isPrimary === true) {
        var p = new Microsoft.Maps.Point(e.getX(), e.getY());
        var t = e.target.tryPixelToLocation(p);
        var l = new Microsoft.Maps.Location(t.latitude, t.longitude);

        // Clear and draw polygon with new point //                  
    }
}
```

How can I get the latitude/longitude of the click when the `targetType` is Polygon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the click event is on a Polygon class use map.tryPixelToLocation as the polygon class doesn't have that function.

Comment: From what I can tell, and from what testing has shown, there is no variable called `map` within the scope of that function.

Comment: The map variable should be available as doesn't appear to be a local variable (no var to the left of it). This would mean it is a global variable, or at least in the same scope as the function getUserClick function.

Comment: Ok, I see what you're saying. It wasn't setup as a global, but setting it as a global and then doing what you suggested does work.